# how to count number of females and males per day (group by) in django

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to group by for dates and count number of field(`choice field : male and female`)

this is what i tried

```
genders = (
   (male , _('male')),
   (female , _('female')),

)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    gender =  models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=genders,default=male)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #others
```

my views.py

```
male= Q(gender='male')
female= Q(gender='female')
lists = MyModel.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('created_at')).values('day').annotate(qnt=Count('id'),male=Count(male),female=Count(female)
).order_by('-day')
```

i expect to return something like this :

```
day : 1-8-2021 , qnt: 15 , male : 8 , female : 7
```

but it return total quantity `qnt` for both male and female ! is there a better approach to achieve that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the count with:

```
data = MyModel.objects.values(
    day=TruncDay('created_at')
).annotate(
    qnt=Count('pk'),
    male=Count('pk', filter=Q(gender='male')),
    female=Count('pk', filter=Q(gender='female'))
).order_by('-day')
```

Comment: wow , i didnt know we can use filter into Count , i wanted to use loop , thank you so much

Comment: sorry , i have a question, which one is more efficient to load data , if i dont use DRF ,  pushing the data into a list dictionary: data=[] , and return JsonResponse or rendering the data

Comment: @HunarMohammed: you should wrap it in a dictionary as outer object, since an outer list has a security vulnerability: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/return-a-jsonresponse-with-safe-false.html

Comment: thank you so much , i did the same something https://dpaste.org/30VS , i just wanted to know a better way to load the data

Comment: can you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643169/how-to-assign-inline-formset-values-to-many-to-many-field-django , i appreciate it